# Using Mocking for unit testing in python

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I have two functions in a `python` file. I want to do some unit tests for these functions using `Mock`.

```
def col_rename(col_name):
    reps = ((' ', '_&'), ('(', '*_'), (')', '_*'), ('{', '#_'), ('}', '_#'))
    new_cols = reduce(lambda a, kv: a.replace(*kv), reps, col_name)
    return new_cols

def rename_characters(df):
    df_cols = df.schema.names
    for x in df_cols:
        df = df.withColumnRenamed(x, col_rename(x))
    return df
```

In the above function `withColumnRenamed` is a function in `pyspark` that will return a column after is renames the column name. 
`df` is a `pyspark` data frame.

I am able to do `unit testing` to the `col_rename` function.

I am able to do `unit testing` to the `rename_characters` function by creating data frames manually in pyspark.

Now I want to do the `unit testing` using `Mock` in `python`.

I have tried something like this below. I am not sure if this is correct or What I am doing is completely wrong

```
import unittest
from mock import patch

class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch('mymodule.rename_characters')
    def test_func(self, rename_characters_mock):
        rename_characters_mock.return_value = 'mocked values'
        self.assertEqual(return_value, 'mocked_values'))
```

How can I do `Mocking` for the `unit testing` as in the above scenario

Comment: `from mymodule import rename_characters`, r u sure we can `import` a func?

Comment: @Gang In `pycharm` it gave me unused import statement error, I removed the import statement

Comment: almost there. it makes more sense if you want to mock `pyspark.x`, `self.assertEqual(return_value, 'mocked_values'))` the return_value is not defined, are u try to `self.assertEqual(mymodule.rename_charaters(), 'mocked_value'` ?

Comment: @Gang I want to try `self.assertEqual(mymodule.rename_charaters(), 'mocked_value'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might need this

```
import mymodule
```

Outside Test class define a local function

```
def local_rename_characters():
    return 'mocked_local_values'
```

This should work

```
@patch('mymodule.rename_characters')
def test_func(self, rename_characters_mock):
    rename_characters_mock.return_value = 'mocked values'
    self.assertEqual(mymodule.rename_characters(), 'mocked_values')
```

Alternatives using `side_effect`

```
@patch('mymodule.rename_characters')
def test_func(self, rename_characters_mock):
    rename_characters_mock.side_effect = local_rename_characters
    self.assertEqual(mymodule.rename_characters(), 'mocked_local_values')
```

Comment: If I want to mock the `withColumnRenamed` method that is inside the `rename_characters` function how can I do that

Comment: `DataFrame` instance is already a variable, u do not really need to mock. but if u do want to play and learn, `@patch('mymodule.pyspark.sql.DataFrame.withColumnRenamed')` and then `mocked_withColumRenamed.side_effect = local_create_dummy_df`, using `createDataFrame`

Comment: could you please have a look at `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49420660/unit-test-pyspark-code-using-python`